# How to use "back home" phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

One can say "get back home" or "went back home" to talk about going back home after hanging out with friends.

> In response to this question: **Who do you usually like to hang out
>   with?** I say: **Back home, I used to hang out with my collage colleagues, but nowadays, I usually go out with my work colleagues**

"back home" refers to my country and the listener know that I am a foreigner. Is this a correct usage of the phrase. Is it idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is idiomatic!

You often hear this used in the exact way you have in your question and it's pretty well established (at least in BrE).

> [**Back Home**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back%20home) - : in one's hometown : in the place one is from

It's worth noting that it's sometimes used to refer to ones house as well, even though this isn't the true definition.

E.g. Someone might say:

> We don't need bread, we have that back home.

This sentence should really be:

> We don't need bread, we have that back **at** home.

Clearly they mean back at the house, rather than in the home country! (Even though they will no doubt have bread "back home").